# How to load scores in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have a simple game published in Google Play. When player wins the game his score should be incremented in leaderboard. My problem is that when player wins the game, app stops. I think that problem is in `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores` because when I removed this part, no one had a problem. Also, I want to notice that not every player has such problem in game. This problem happens just to those, who haven't ever won the game (they have no score in leaderboard). So,  `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores` works only to those who already have some score in leaderboard.

My script:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(GPGSIds.leaderboard_rating, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.LeaderboardStart.PlayerCentered, 1, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.LeaderboardCollection.Public, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime, (GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.LeaderboardScoreData data) =>
{
    long score;
    if (long.TryParse(data.PlayerScore.formattedValue, out score))
        Social.ReportScore(score + 50, GPGSIds.leaderboard_rating, (bool success) => { });
    else
        Social.ReportScore(50, GPGSIds.leaderboard_rating, (bool success) => { });
});
```

Comment: Can you try setting the scores of all players to default 0 so players who havent played yet can make calls to loadScores ?

Comment: @noogui thanks. It helped me

Comment: Gj! Good to hear it's working for you.

Comment: @ReyAnthonyRenacia that was my problem thanks a lot ! (and thanks irakliy01 for the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [google sample from github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

Using `PlayGamesPlatform.LoadScores()`

This method uses the PlayGamesPlatform directly. This approach provides additional flexibility and information when accessing the leaderboard data.

```
 PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
            GPGSIds.leaderboard_leaders_in_smoketesting,
            LeaderboardStart.PlayerCentered,
            100,
            LeaderboardCollection.Public,
            LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
            (data) =>
            {
                mStatus = "Leaderboard data valid: " + data.Valid;
                mStatus += "\n approx:" +data.ApproximateCount + " have " + data.Scores.Length;
            });
```

The parameters for `LoadScores()` are:

> leaderboardId start position (top scores or player centered) row count
>   leaderboard collection (social or public) time span (daily, weekly,
>   all-time) callback accepting a LeaderboardScoreData object. The
>   LeaderboardScoreData class is used to return information back to the
>   caller when loading scores. The members are: 
>    1. Id - the leaderboard id 2. Valid - true if the returned data is valid (the call was successful) 3. Status - the ResponseStatus of the
>   call 4. ApproximateCount - the approximate number of scores in the
>   leaderboard 5. Title - the title of the leaderboard 6. PlayerScore -
>   the score of the current player 7. Scores - the list of scores 8.
>   PrevPageToken - a token that can be used to call LoadMoreScores() to
>   get the previous page of scores. 9. NextPageToken - a token that can
>   be used to call LoadMoreScores() to get the next page of scores.

```
void GetNextPage(LeaderboardScoreData data)
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadMoreScores(data.NextPageToken, 10,
            (results) =>
            {
                mStatus = "Leaderboard data valid: " + data.Valid;
                mStatus += "\n approx:" +data.ApproximateCount + " have " + data.Scores.Length;
            });
    }
```

Additional reference [How to get the user score value from Google Play Services Leaderboard](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/767795/how-to-get-the-user-score-value-from-google-play-s.html).

**P.S.:**

Try setting the scores of all players to default 0 so players who havent played yet can make calls to loadScores.